# In the bibliography it is written S. 226 instead p. 226

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

In the bibliography, german Seiten (S.) is written for the pages but I want to change to pages (p.) instead. Can someone help me to change the settings? I am using TexStudio.

main tex file

```
\documentclass[fontsize = 12pt,                     %Schriftgröße
               paper = a4,                              %Papierformat
               headings = small,                    %Größe der Überschriften
               open=right,                              %Abschnitte beginnen rechts
               cleardoublepage = empty,     %leere Seiten ohne Kopfzeile
               BCOR = 10mm,                             %Binde Korrektur
               captions = tableheading,     %Tabellen mit Überschriften
               bibliography = totoc,            %Literatur- ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
               listof = totoc,                      %Verzeichnisse ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
               %twoside = true
               oneside
               ]                        %doppelseitiges Layout
              {scrbook}
        
\usepackage{setspace}            % Zeilenabstand einstellbar
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} %tabellen mit farben
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %für die größe von bildern
\usepackage{listings} %statt verbatim?
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage{float}        % u.a. genaue Plazierung von Gleitobjekten mit H
\usepackage{textcomp}       %für \textregistred in Überschrift
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand{\bf}{\normalfont \bfseries} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  %zur Darstellung von Quelltexten
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}    
    
\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\frontmatter
\clearpage
%-----Titelblatt, Kurzfassung und Abstract-----
\include{titel}
\clearpage

%-----Kurzfassung-----
\clearpage
\include{Kurzfassung}

%------Foreword------
\clearpage 
\include{Preface}

%-----Inhaltsverzeichnis-----
\clearpage                           
\tableofcontents             

%-----Abbildungsverzeichnis-----
\clearpage
\listoffigures

%-----Tabellenverzeichnis-----
\clearpage     
\listoftables

%-----Listings-----
\clearpage     
\lstlistoflistings


%-----List of Abbreviations----
%\clearpage
%\include{Abrreviations}


%-----Tabellenverzeichnis-----
\clearpage
\include{Abbreviations}

\clearpage
\include{Glossary}



%-----Hauptkapitel-----
\mainmatter             % den Hauptteil beginnen
\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}  % Kopfzeilen
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}  % Kopfzeilen
\include{kapitel_1}
\include{kapitel_2}
\include{kapitel_3}
\include{kapitel_4}
\include{kapitel_5}
%-----Anhang-----
\include{Anhang}
%\include{Glossary}
%\include{literatur}
%\listoftables
%\listoffigures
\bibliographystyle{plaindin} %Verzeichnis nach Autor sortiert, Referenzen numerisch
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin} %Verzeichnis in Reihenfolge des zitierens, Referenzen numerisch 
%\bibliographystyle{alphadin} %Verzeichnis nach Autor sortiert, Referenzen aus Autorenkürzel
%\bibliographystyle{abbrvdin} % Wie plaindin, Autorenvornamen abgekürzt
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\nocite{*}               % Alle Quelleneintr?ge anzeigen, auch wenn sie nicht im Text referenziert sind
%-----Aufgaben der Bachelorarbeit-----
%\clearpage
\include{Erklaerung}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Literatur.bib

```
@inproceedings{Behringer.2004,
    title        = {The DARPA grand challenge - development of an autonomous vehicle},
    author       = {Behringer, R. and Sundareswaran, S. and Daily, R. and Bevly, D. and Gregory, B. and Elsley, R. and Addison, B. and Guthmiller, W.},
    year         = 2004,
    booktitle    = {IEEE Intelligent Vehicles Symposium, 2004},
    publisher    = {IEEE},
    pages        = {226-231},
    doi          = {10.1109/IVS.2004.1336386},
    isbn         = {0-7803-8310-9}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would say that this may well be due to you loading the `bibgerm` package. This is a rather old package, which probably should not be used anymore anyway. And it was specifically designed to, well, give German bibliographies. If you want an English document, including English bibliography terms, just use an English citation style.

Comment: And some more remarks: (1) You load `hyperref` too early. This is one of the LaTeX packages where load order really matters and `hyperref` should be (with very few exceptions) the last package you load. (2) Unless you really need to go the dvips-route, you could run pdfLaTeX directly and then probably get rid of `epstopdf`. (3) Using `nocite{*}` to just cite everything in your bibliography file somehow defeats the purpose of using a reference manager anyway, and is definitely not correct. If you want to cite additional literature, maybe include it as a separate "Further Reading" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document is in English, why use `bibgerm`?

Anyway, you should use a bibliography style tailored for the package, for instance `gerplain`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Behringer.2004,
    title        = {The DARPA grand challenge - development of an autonomous vehicle},
    author       = {Behringer, R. and Sundareswaran, S. and Daily, R. and Bevly, D. and Gregory, B. and Elsley, R. and Addison, B. and Guthmiller, W.},
    year         = 2004,
    booktitle    = {IEEE Intelligent Vehicles Symposium, 2004},
    publisher    = {IEEE},
    pages        = {226-231},
    doi          = {10.1109/IVS.2004.1336386},
    isbn         = {0-7803-8310-9}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[
  fontsize = 12pt,         %Schriftgröße
  paper = a4,              %Papierformat
  open=right,              %Abschnitte beginnen rechts
  cleardoublepage = empty, %leere Seiten ohne Kopfzeile
  BCOR = 10mm,             %Binde Korrektur
  captions = tableheading, %Tabellen mit Überschriften
  bibliography = totoc,    %Literatur- ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
  listof = totoc,          %Verzeichnisse ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
  %twoside = true,         %doppelseitiges Layout
  oneside,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\renewcommand{\sc}{\scshape}

\nocite{*} % Alle Quelleneintr?ge anzeigen, auch wenn sie nicht im Text referenziert sind

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\bibliographystyle{gerplain} %Verzeichnis nach Autor sortiert, Referenzen numerisch
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The department in the university, where I am currently writing my thesis, gave me a latex template. Packages came with that template including bibgerm.

Comment: @SilverShroud Oh, well, it's a badly written template. Probably more than 20 year old, with packages added in a wrong order, a lot of useless `\clearpage` commands…

Comment: @egregThank you btw. It is now fixed. DOI urls are excluded now but anyway page problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `bibgerm`, which, well, is an untranslated German style.

You probably should not be using this rather ancient package, and instead be doing something like `\bibliographystyle{alphadin}` (depending on what style you actually want).